# Google contacts import failing

Tags: csv, import, contacts, google-workspace

anyone experienced issues with importing contacts through CSV file into Google Contacts? I have a CSV file with little over 7300 contacts, and it's importing in one Google account completely fine, but in other it's just giving error "Can't import contacts" - "Something went wrong. Try again later."

I tried cutting the file to be under 3000 lines, just like knowledge base says, no luck.

It seems like something is f#ucked up with the account on Google's side, blocking the import.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Google contacts does not explicitly give you information on what headers to use.  Don't assume they will accept your headers, even if yours are commonly used.
I have had success by exporting some contacts from Google to see what headers they use then importing.
See my answer to: [Google Contacts failing to import correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352611/google-contacts-failing-to-import-correctly/67807985#67807985)

Don't try to make sense of the error messages, even if it says to "Try again later".  The headers, and not time (or the size of your file) may be the issue.
See: https://www.timeatlas.com/import-contacts-to-gmail/